# why do I need to reset the delimiter at the end of the stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this stored procedure:

Why do I need to reset the delimiter? If I don't reset the delimiter I should be able to use the "$$" instead of the  ";"

```
DELIMITER $$
/* This is a complete statement, not part of the procedure, so use the custom delimiter $$ */
 DROP PROCEDURE selectSales$$

/* Now start the procedure code */
CREATE PROCEDURE selectSales()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM sales;
  
/* whole procedure ends with the custom delimiter */
END$$

/* I'm not resetting the delimiter, so I should be able to use "$$" instead of ";" */

SELECT * from sales$$  <--- gives syntax error
SELECT * from sales
```

Comment: I don't get a syntax error when I test a similar case. What client are you using? The `mysql` command-line shell? What does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: It gives me 8.0.23

Comment: In shown particular case you do not need in delimiter reassign at all - SP contains one single statement and does not need in BEGIN-END block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you.

See console output:

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE sales SELECT 11 id;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.53 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE selectSales()
    -> BEGIN
    ->     SELECT * FROM sales;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT * from sales$$
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 11 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Of course it is possible that you did something not listed in your description...